# How to subtract the value of previous datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with aggregated data from hedge fund in PostgreSQL looking like following:

[image: Data about Total Balance and Inflow/outflow with corresponding strategy]

Let's say the table is called `a`. I want to create column using the following formula for each `Strategy`:

```
(TotalBalancePosition(t) - Total_Balance(t-1) - PriceInDollars(t) / TotalBalancePosition(t-1)
```

where `t` is indicating today and `t - 1` the previous day (or just the previous datetime) of column `TimeUTC` (when balance and transaction (price in dollars) were taken). Both `TotalBalancePosition` and `PriceInDollars` are columns with float values.

In other words, I want to create the column of day-by-day growth of Total Balance with including the column `PriceInDollars` in total growth.

I assume we must use window function `partition by`, but it confuses me what should I do to specify that we subtract the previous day:

```
select 
    "TimeUTC", "Strategy", 
    (("TotalBalancePosition"(t) - "TotalBalancePosition"(t - 1) - coalesce("PriceInDollars", 0)) / "TotalBalancePosition"(t - 1)) over (partition by "Strategy" order by "TimeUTC" desc) as "Return",   
    "PriceInDollars"  
from 
    a
```

Comment: Are `Total_Balance` and `PriceInDollars` actually functions or column names?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver, they are column names. I want to take TotalBalance and PriceInDollars of previous day, the script is pseudo-code.

Comment: [PostgreSQL LAG Function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lag-function/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ponder Stibbons figured out that we should use `lag` function with `partion by` with ordering of datetime value.

```
select "TimeUTC", "Strategy", 
COALESCE((("TotalBalancePosition" - lag("TotalBalancePosition", 1) over (partition by "Strategy" order by "TimeUTC") - (
-1 * coalesce("PriceInDollars", 0))) / nullif(lag("TotalBalancePosition", 1) over (partition by "Strategy" order by "TimeUTC"), 0)), 0) as "Return" 
from a
```